# Scanning computers from Active Directory for Local Admin accounts

Tags: active-directory, admin, scanning

I need to scan Active Directory and pipe the information into a local admin checking script. But for some reason this script keeps failing. It fails at

```
$Group = $computer.psbase.children.find(”Administrators”)
```

Here is the script

```
 ################################################
 #Start looking for windows 10 & computers 7    #
 ################################################
$root = {Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "win10*"} | Select -Property Name
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*win7"} | Select -Property Name}
foreach ($server in $root)
 {
$computer = [ADSI](”WinNT://” + "$server" + “,computer”)
$Group = $computer.psbase.children.find(”Administrators”)
$members = ($Group.psbase.invoke(”Members”) | %{$_.GetType().InvokeMember(”Adspath”, ‘GetProperty’, $null, $_, $null)}) -  replace ('WinNT://DOMAIN/' + $server + '/'), '' -replace ('WinNT://DOMAIN/', 'DOMAIN\') -replace ('WinNT://', '')
 $members  }
```

Comment: What is the error message that it tells you?

Comment: At line:7 char:122
+ ... .InvokeMember(”Adspath”, ‘GetProperty’, $null, $_, $null)}) -  replac ...
+                                                               You must provide a value expression following the '-' operator.
At line:7 char:124 + ... mber(”Adspath”, ‘GetProperty’, $null, $_, $null)}) -  replace ('WinNT ...
+                                                           ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'replace' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression

Answer (score 0):

You were looking at the wrong line. It's the `$members =` line that it's complaining about. You have two spaces between the hyphen and your first "replace":

```
-  replace ('WinNT://DOMAIN/' + $server + '/')
```

There shouldn't be any spaces there. Try this:

```
$root = {Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "win10*"} | Select -Property Name
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*win7"} | Select -Property Name}
foreach ($server in $root)
{
    $computer = [ADSI](”WinNT://” + "$server" + “,computer”)
    $Group = $computer.psbase.children.find(”Administrators”)
    $members = ($Group.psbase.invoke(”Members”) | %{$_.GetType().InvokeMember(”Adspath”, ‘GetProperty’, $null, $_, $null)}) -replace ('WinNT://DOMAIN/' + $server + '/'), '' -replace ('WinNT://DOMAIN/', 'DOMAIN\') -replace ('WinNT://', '')
    $members
}
```

If you aren't already, try using the Windows PowerShell ISE, which is included in Windows, for writing PowerShell scripts. It will highlight simple syntax errors like that.

Comment: Yeah, i am already using ISE. I tried what you thought was wrong and im still getting errors.

Comment: Find" with "1" argument(s): "The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:6 char:5  + $Group = $computer.psbase.children.find(”Administrators”)   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMException

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:7 char:5 +   $members = ($Group.psbase.invoke(”Members”) | %{$_.GetType().Invo ...
 + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: So line 7 is failing because line 6 failed. Is that the complete error message for line 6? Does it tell you what file it was looking for?